# exception handling, creating log and continue the program in JAVA

Tags: java, exception, text, io, iteration

I am designing a program in JAVA that captures results in about 10 iterations. At the end of these iterations all the results must be written into a log file.

If any exception occurs then it should be written on my text file and secondly the program must not stop, it must go on till the last iteration is completed...

That is to say - if some error occur on any part of any iteration the *program must not stop* here. The error must be mentioned within my results by the name of error and it must go on and update my log file.

My code till now is bit lengthy...used try-catch, the try block is doing my calculations and writing my text file, but I need if incase some exception occurs my program must not stop and that exception must be updated in my log file.

Comment: Show us your code so we can see all the effort you've put in so far.

Comment: my code till now is bit lengthy...used try-catch, the try block is doing my calculations and writing my text file,
but i need if incase some exception occours my program must not stop and that exception must be updated in my log file...

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `try`-`catch` block. See, for example, [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Answer (score 1):

```
OutputStream os = ....;
PrintStream  ps = new PrintStream(os);

while(notDone) {
    try {
        doStuff();
    }
    catch(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace(ps);
    }
    ps.print(results);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the case is, in this kind of a question, you should better provide us a sample code, then only we can identify the problem without any issue.

If you just need to view the error, then "e.printStackTrace" will help you. The "e" is an instance of class "Exception".

However, if you need to LOG, then "Logger" class will help you, with Exception class.For an example,

```
try {
                    f = location.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(TestForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
```

To do all of these, it is better to surround your code with try catch block